# Better way of writing this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have an MySQL query

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE B.AID = A.ID) AS Sum1,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM C WHERE C.AID = A.ID) AS Sum2
FROM A
```

What are possible alternatives using joins or so?

Comment: That's not a `JOIN`-able query since the two counts might differ.

Comment: Consider providing a more concrete example in the form of a sqlfiddle and/or set of DDLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work if there are unique IDs in the B and C tables.  In my example the fields are called ID.

```
SELECT A.*,
       COUNT(DISTINCT B.ID) AS Sum1,
       COUNT(DISTINCT C.ID) AS Sum2

FROM   A

       LEFT JOIN B ON b.AID = A.ID
       LEFT JOIN C ON C.AID = A.ID

GROUP BY A.ID
```

Comment: this one seems equivalent to my query and performs similary.
i just don't understand, how MySQL counts very fast

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A.*, IFNULL(t1.sum, 0), IFNULL(t2.sum, 0)
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT AID, COUNT(AID) sum FROM B GROUP BY AID) t1 ON t1.AID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT AID, COUNT(AID) sum FROM C GROUP BY AID) t2 ON t2.AID = A.ID
```

Comment: You're running on a lot of assumptions here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, here is how it could be achieved using a `join`: BUT with assumptions..that your tables look like the sample I have used as a demo. If it's not, please share with us your table schema and sample data, with your expected results...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e65c/2

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, 
CASE WHEN B.AID = A.ID THEN COUNT(*) END AS SUM1,
CASE WHEN B.AID = A.ID THEN COUNT(*) END AS SUM1
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.AID
INNER JOIN C
ON B.AID = C.AID
GROUP BY A.ID, A.NAME
;

SELECT A.ID, A.NAME,  COUNT(B.AID) AS SUM1,
COUNT(C.AID) AS SUM1
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.AID
INNER JOIN C
ON B.AID = C.AID
GROUP BY A.ID, A.NAME
;

| ID | NAME | SUM1 |
--------------------
|  1 | John |    2 |
|  2 |  Tim |    4 |
|  3 | Jack |    2 |
```